# Python, Pandas, sum only taking uniques

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

An Excel spreadsheet like below (note: ID the column A has duplicated values). I want to find out sum of each Contract_type, taking each ID is counted once only (unique).

[image]

```
data = {'ID': ["380689","380689","480562","480562","480562","14805","47089","56251","56251","56251","322624","322624","322624","85964","85964","85964","342225","342225","4589","23591","23591","235225"], 
'Contract_type' : ["Other","Other","Type-I","Type-I","Type-I","Type-II","Type-II","Type-II","Type-II","Type-II","Type-II","Type-II","Type-II","Type-III","Type-III","Type-III","Part-time","Part-time","Part-time","Full-time","Full-time","Full-time"],
'Unit_Weight': [335,335,119,119,119,119,52,452,452,452,19,19,19,165,165,165,165,165,165,724,724,16],
'Test_time' : ["16:26","07:39","18:48","22:32","03:54","03:30","09:57","18:52","19:03","18:06","18:52","03:51","04:00","22:02","13:35","13:43","10:29","06:30","12:20","12:52","17:30","13:10"],
'Tested' : [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
'Internal' : [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried:

```
print pd.pivot_table(df, index = ["Contract_type", "ID"]).Unit_Weight
```

It gives:

```
Contract_type  ID    
Full-time      23591     724
               235225     16
Other          380689    335
....
```

But I only want it to show something like: Full-time 740 etc.

I also tried:

```
print pd.pivot_table(df, index = ["Contract_type"], values=["Unit_Weight"], aggfunc = np.sum)
```

It gives:

```
Full-time             1464  # this is not considering the duplicated IDs
```

What's the right way to right the line? Thank you.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Please, no data as images, as always...

Comment: @jezrael, hello sir. like Full-time 740, Other 335, Part-time 330, Type-I 119, Type-II 642, Type-III 165

Comment: Why is other -> 335 and not 670?

Comment: @SpghttCd, the Other has 2 the same ID 380689, of each 335. I want it only count once.

Comment: Ah, that's my misunderstanding, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to only take each (ID, Contract-Type) couple into account only once, so I don't think `df.groupby(['Contract_type', 'ID]).Unit_Weight.sum()` would work.

Instead you can try:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Contract_type', 'ID']).groupby('Contract_type').Unit_Weight.sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think need:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['Contract_type', 'ID'])
        .set_index('Contract_type')['Unit_Weight']
        .sum(level=0)
        .reset_index())

print (df1)
  Contract_type  Unit_Weight
0         Other          335
1        Type-I          119
2       Type-II          642
3      Type-III          165
4     Part-time          330
5     Full-time          740
```

Comment: it's a great learning session. wish you a very good weekend @jezrael

Comment: @MarkK - Thank you, for you too. :)

Comment: This answer won't work since `x.unique()` will apply on the Unit_weight column, which means that two rows with different IDs but the same contract_type and same unit_weight will only be accounted for once

Comment: @jezrael, sir, the Part-time: 165 from your answer is wrong. could you please have a look?

Comment: @MarkK - It is 3 times `165`, what is expected output for `Part-time` ?

Comment: @MarkK - Now understand, need check dupes for both columns. Check edited answer, similar by Alexandre Uzan solution.

Comment: @jezrael, Sorry, sir. I take Alexandre Uzan's for the answer, to be fair. Can I have your kind understanding?

Comment: @MarkK - Yes, but problem is expected output from image data is not easy check...

Comment: @jezrael, my bad on that. deduct my points...I shall had provide the data instead of picture in question at the beginning.